# Initial Segments and Isomorphism

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $f:X \to Y$ be an order isomorphism and A be an initial segment of X. 
Show that $f[A]$ is an initial segment of Y.

I believe this has something to do with Cantor's theorem but can't quite figure it out.

I'm assuming I'll use the fact that order isomorphisms are a bijective map that preserves order somewhere in the proof.

Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: $A$ is an initial segment of $X$ if and only if for all $y\in A$ and all $x\in X$ with $x<y$ we have $x\in A.$ You must show that $f[A]$ is an initial segment of $Y,$ meaning that for all $y'\in f[A]$ and all $x'\in Y$ with $x'<y',$ we have $x'\in f[A]$.

The proof is fairly straightforward. You will indeed use the fact that $f$ is order-preserving and bijective, along with the definition of $f[A],$ namely: $$f[A]=\bigl\{f(z):z\in A\bigr\}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It was very helpful! I think I'm getting tripped up by the $f[A]$ notation. I've learned about it but can you remind me what is is please.

Comment: Glad to help! I have added the definition to my answer. Let me know if you still aren't getting anywhere, or if you just want me to double-check your approach.